# Elasticsearch-- Different number of hits for the same query, caused by JDBC indexing errors

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch index with 5 shards, holding just over 20,000 records. It is being fully re-indexed each night. Simple term searches for common words return a different number of 'hits' on different days, even when no new records are added. I see that the document counts for [terms aggregation queries are approximate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-approximate-counts).

However, I don't see documentation that search term queries return approximate totals. Has anyone else seen this effect with simple term queries? What can I do to get exact totals (or at least consistent totals)?

As an initial change, I am moving to a single shard, but I would like to know if there is any documentation of the issue I am seeing.

**UPDATE:** I retested and found that the JDBC driver we are using did not index the whole database each time. This issue is referenced [here](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc/issues/143), and requires changes in the JDBC driver parameters.

Comment: Is it always the exact same data set that is being reindexed (i.e. same documents and same document count)? Also can you clarify whether you're talking about the number of `hits` (i.e. search results) or the number of terms in an `aggregation`?

Comment: Yes, it is the same data set being re-indexed. The number of hits is coming back different for plain searches. We are not doing any aggregation.